# Why are all the values being appended to the list winning_numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, jupyter-notebook

I am working in Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.6. I do not understand why all the values are being appended to winning_numbers instead of losing_numbers where they should.

My code:

```
import numpy as np

winning_numbers = []
losing_numbers = []

limit = 11

for x in range(1, limit):

    if x%2 == 0:

        if x-1 or x/2 in losing_numbers:
            winning_numbers.append(x)

        elif x-1 and x/2 in winning_numbers:
            losing_numbers.append(x)

    if x%2 == 1:

        if x-1 == 0:
            winning_numbers.append(x)

        elif x-1 or (x-1)/2 in losing_numbers:
            winning_numbers.append(x)

        elif x-1 and (x-1)/2 in winning_numbers:
            losing_numbers.append(x)

print("Winning Numbers: ", winning_numbers)
print("Losing Numbers: ", losing_numbers)
```

My output is:

```
Winning Numbers:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Losing Numbers:  []
```

The output should be:

```
Winning Numbers: [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
Losing Numbers: [2, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way your organized the `or` in your `if` statement:

```
if x-1 or x/2 in losing_numbers:
```

This means:

```
if (x-1) or (x/2 in losing_numbers):
```

Since for all integer values of `x` except for 1, `x-1` is `truthy`, this will always evaluate to true and `x` will be appended to `winning_numbers`.

You should rewrite it as:

```
if x-1 in losing_numbers or x/2 in losing_numbers:
```

or:

```
if any(k in theQuestion for k in (x-1, x/2))
```